# How to install Form Based Authentication in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, fba

I would like users to have the ability of signing in without being Windows users. This means, either using Form Based Authentication or a better option, which I'm now aware right now.

Could anybody tell me how to install FBA in Share Point 2010, or recommend me a good article about it?

I've read several articles about this, but almost all of them tell me to modify several web.config files, and I really don't like the idea of touching things without being sure of what I'm doing.

Note: I'm not using Active Directory...just in case.

**EDIT:**

I've followed [this tutorial](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mahesm/archive/2010/04/07/configure-forms-based-authentication-fba-with-sharepoint-2010.aspx), but I still cannot sign in using FBA. Also, I've noticed I don't have any users on SQL-Auth database (it's explained in that tutorial). Is that normal, or automatic?

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read quite a few articles about FBA configuration and followed instruction provided by them. But it wasn't until I found [Configuring Forms Based Authentication for SharePoint 2010 using IIS7](http://donalconlon.wordpress.com/2010/02/23/configuring-forms-base-authentication-for-sharepoint-2010-using-iis7/) I finally managed to make FBA work - I highly recommend this article.

---

The users are not created automatically - you can create them:

- using *IIS Manager*,
- programmatically ([`Membership.CreateUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.createuser.aspx)),
- using the *MembershipSeeder* tool mentioned in the tutorial you linked in your question.

Comment: I'll give it a try and I will let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This one has lots of screenshots and step-by-step explanations and might be helpful too.

http://kbochevski.blogspot.com/2011/01/setup-fba-for-sharepoint-2010-using-vs.html